# AutoRunnable application for USB

Tags: language-agnostic, usb-drive

I want to make an application which will reside in USB and as soon USB is plugged it will open Google.com in its default browser(It should run in all platform Mac,Windows,Linux). I tried making Autorun.inf file but it didn't help.I will appreciate any kind of help in this matter.

Comment: If you don't care about the language, tag it language-agnostic, don't just throw in 9001 language tags.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a browser resident on the same USB. 
There's a version of portable Chrome on portableapps.com

Comment: what If I want to open my Web App as soon as USB is plugged?